# Web Bluetooth can't find anything on computer

Tags: javascript, web, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I'm currently trying to get a bit familiar with web bluetooth. For that, I tried to use https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/

On an Android 7 Phone I can perfectly find my BLE device with the "Device Info (Promises)" function.

But on any computer I tried this doesn't work. I tried it on a Windows 10, Ubuntu and Mac Computer. It fails on the dialog on which it searches devices. It doesn't find any devices and fails after some minutes with an error that it haven't found any devices.

Any idea what this is? Is this a general issue on this "new" technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Implementation Status](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md) page lists more details, but a summary as of 2017-08-14:

- Chrome

  - Android M and later
  - ChromeOS
  - macOS ([must have BLE](https://superuser.com/questions/702670/how-can-i-tell-if-my-mac-has-bluetooth-4-0-low-energy))
  - Linux & Windows only partial, enabled with `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`

    - [Linux may need needs even more setup](https://www.espruino.com/Web+Bluetooth+On+Linux).
- Samsung Internet 6.2

  - Android, enabled with `internet://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth`

--

So, your Linux machine may need [setup](https://www.espruino.com/Web+Bluetooth+On+Linux). Windows implementation is just not complete. And the macOS machine may not have BLE?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, thanks! The firstly tried Linux machine had no BLE, same for the Mac. Got it now working on another Linux machine with BLE. Worked out of the box with Ubuntu.